# function composition with itself, infinite iteration

Tags: functional-analysis

Is it possible to find out what the "limit" is as the number of iterations of compositions a certain function with itself, like a trig function for example, tends to infinity?

1. $\sin(\sin(\sin(\dots(\sin(x))\dots)))$
2. $\cos(\cos(\cos(\dots(\cos(x))\dots)))$

In the first one, I'm composing sine with itself infinitely many times and in the second, I'm composing cosine with itself.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that $\sin(x) \in [-1,1]$ and for $x \in [-1,1]$ we have $\lvert \sin(x) \lvert \leq \lvert x \rvert$. This shows that it converges.

In fact, you could also just use Banachs Fixed Point theorem. And you'll see that the sequence will converge to the fixedpoints of $\sin$ and $\cos$ (in the interval $[-1,1]$).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

Just consider the sequence defined by induction:

$$\begin{cases} u_0=x \\ u_{n+1}=f(u_n). \end{cases}$$

where $f$ is the function you consider (here $\sin$ and $\cos$).

Then look at the limit

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} u_n$$

with the usuals theorems.